# Session is not saved from crossdomain connection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cross-domain

I've got an Asp.Mvc web site with allowed cross-domain authorization and I need to create js file thats will allow to connect to my site. This script is some kind of API wich is necessary to make connection from different sites. I'm testing it on my local IIS server on simply HTML page, when it's sending log in data, users information is saved in httpContext successfully, but at next query users data in Session is empty. I don't know is it true, but it looks like  all queries makes their own sessions on server. So what should I do to fix session for cross-domain connection?

UPD. I've found that in httpContext on every query, Sessions ID is always different, but I still don't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do Cross domain request you can never set session for the requested domain/server. It is the duty of Domain B to set its session. The Domain A can never set  session.

Comment: I'm creating all users data in session on mvc server side. Or what do you mean?